# Vertical align in editor, Smart Slider 3 Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, slider

maybe it´s a dumb question, but still. I am using Smart Slider plugin in wordpress, and when i tried to addapt my sliders for small devices i found next problem. In my editor the slider only shows me the option to addapt everything for devices in horizonal view/mode:
[image: Horizontal view]

I just can´t switch it to normal vertical mode. The curious thing, when i check a preview it shows me the result in vertical view.

[image: preview]

But basically the question is: How i switch t horizontal and vertical view for small devices to addapt my content.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think i already figure it out. It shows you only the height and the width of the slider given in your options, and not the entire height of the device.